# How do I prevent my Google Chat from showing my status as "idle"?

Tags: google-talk

I am being watched by the boss. I want my status to show as "active" all the time even when I step away from my desk.

Any way to make it appear as active 100% of the time?

Comment: Is this the same as "hangouts"?

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to install additional programs on your work computer?  If so, you could use a chat client capable of using Google Chat, such as [Pidgin](http://www.pidgin.im/).  Pidgin allows you to set the time before it reports idle or allows you disable going idle completely.

Even if you can't install it at work, you can install it on a home computer and it should keep you from appearing offline.  I have Pidgin installed on my home computers and chats received there still appear in my Gmail chat window when I'm at work.